# Minimalist Golomb-Rice coder

Tags: performance, c, compression

I have implemented a very simple but robust implementation of [the Golomb-Rice coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding).
To understand my motivation, see [the minimalist data compressor](https://github.com/xbarin02/x-compressor) that is based on this.
At the moment, the implementation works well.
However, I intend to make it more elegant, concise, and possibly faster.
Any suggestions for improvement or constructive criticism are welcome.

### Prerequisites

- The `typedef` name `uint32` designates an unsigned integer type with width exactly 32 bits.
- The `uchar` name is an alias for `unsigned char`.
- Function `size_t minsize(size_t a, size_t b)` returns the minimum of `a` and `b`.
- Function `size_t ctzu32(uint32 n)` returns the number of trailing 0-bits in `n`, starting at the least significant bit position. If `n` is 0, the result is 32.

### Code

The implementation uses the following data structure:

```
enum {
    BIO_MODE_READ,
    BIO_MODE_WRITE
};

struct bio {
    int mode;   /* reading or writing? */
    uchar *ptr; /* pointer to memory */
    uint32 b;   /* bit buffer */
    size_t c;   /* bit counter */
};
```

Furthermore, I use several auxiliary functions (it is a bit long):

```
static void bio_reset_after_flush(struct bio *bio)
{
    assert(bio != NULL);

    bio->b = 0;
    bio->c = 0;
}

static void bio_open(struct bio *bio, uchar *ptr, int mode)
{
    assert(bio != NULL);
    assert(ptr != NULL);

    bio->mode = mode;
    bio->ptr = ptr;

    switch (mode) {
        case BIO_MODE_READ:
            bio->c = 32;
            break;
        case BIO_MODE_WRITE:
            bio_reset_after_flush(bio);
            break;
    }
}

static void bio_flush_buffer(struct bio *bio)
{
    assert(bio != NULL);
    assert(bio->ptr != NULL);
    assert(sizeof(uint32) * CHAR_BIT == 32);

    *((uint32 *)bio->ptr) = bio->b;

    bio->ptr += 4;
}

static void bio_reload_buffer(struct bio *bio)
{
    assert(bio != NULL);
    assert(bio->ptr != NULL);

    bio->b = *(uint32 *)bio->ptr;

    bio->ptr += 4;
}

static void bio_put_nonzero_bit(struct bio *bio)
{
    assert(bio != NULL);
    assert(bio->c < 32);

    bio->b |= (uint32)1 << bio->c;

    bio->c++;

    if (bio->c == 32) {
        bio_flush_buffer(bio);
        bio_reset_after_flush(bio);
    }
}

static void bio_write_bits(struct bio *bio, uint32 b, size_t n)
{
    assert(n <= 32);

    while (n > 0) {
        size_t m;

        assert(bio->c < 32);

        m = minsize(32 - bio->c, n);

        assert(32 >= bio->c + m);

        bio->b |= (uint32)((b & (((uint32)1 << m) - 1)) << bio->c);

        bio->c += m;

        if (bio->c == 32) {
            bio_flush_buffer(bio);
            bio_reset_after_flush(bio);
        }

        b >>= m;
        n -= m;
    }
}

static void bio_write_zero_bits(struct bio *bio, size_t n)
{
    assert(n <= 32);

    while (n > 0) {
        size_t m;

        assert(bio->c < 32);

        m = minsize(32 - bio->c, n);

        assert(32 >= bio->c + m);

        bio->c += m;

        if (bio->c == 32) {
            bio_flush_buffer(bio);
            bio_reset_after_flush(bio);
        }

        n -= m;
    }
}

static uint32 bio_read_bits(struct bio *bio, size_t n)
{
    uint32 w;
    size_t s;

    /* reload? */
    if (bio->c == 32) {
        bio_reload_buffer(bio);
        bio->c = 0;
    }

    /* get the avail. least-significant bits */
    s = minsize(32 - bio->c, n);

    w = bio->b & (((uint32)1 << s) - 1);

    bio->b >>= s;
    bio->c += s;

    n -= s;

    /* need more bits? reload & get the most-significant bits */
    if (n > 0) {
        assert(bio->c == 32);

        bio_reload_buffer(bio);
        bio->c = 0;

        w |= (bio->b & (((uint32)1 << n) - 1)) << s;

        bio->b >>= n;
        bio->c += n;
    }

    return w;
}

static void bio_close(struct bio *bio)
{
    assert(bio != NULL);

    if (bio->mode == BIO_MODE_WRITE && bio->c > 0) {
        bio_flush_buffer(bio);
    }
}

static void bio_write_unary(struct bio *bio, uint32 N)
{
    while (N > 32) {
        bio_write_zero_bits(bio, 32);

        N -= 32;
    }

    bio_write_zero_bits(bio, N);

    bio_put_nonzero_bit(bio);
}

static uint32 bio_read_unary(struct bio *bio)
{
    /* get zeros... */
    uint32 total_zeros = 0;

    assert(bio != NULL);

    do {
        size_t s;

        /* reload? */
        if (bio->c == 32) {
            bio_reload_buffer(bio);
            bio->c = 0;
        }

        /* get trailing zeros */
        s = minsize(32 - bio->c, ctzu32(bio->b));

        bio->b >>= s;
        bio->c += s;

        total_zeros += s;
    } while (bio->c == 32);

    /* ...and drop non-zero bit */
    assert(bio->c < 32);

    bio->b >>= 1;
    bio->c++;

    return total_zeros;
}
```

Finally, the main entry functions (that encode/decode non-negative integer `N` using parameter `2^k`) are defined as follows:

```
void bio_write_gr(struct bio *bio, size_t k, uint32 N)
{
    uint32 Q = N >> k;

    bio_write_unary(bio, Q);

    assert(k <= 32);

    bio_write_bits(bio, N, k);
}

uint32 bio_read_gr(struct bio *bio, size_t k)
{
    uint32 Q;
    uint32 N;

    Q = bio_read_unary(bio);

    N = Q << k;

    assert(k <= 32);

    N |= bio_read_bits(bio, k);

    return N;
}
```

Comment: OT: the function: `assert()` should not be in production code and does not display the information needed when debugging

Comment: @user3629249 Quoting from the corresponding man page: _If the macro `NDEBUG` is defined at the moment `<assert.h>` was last included, the macro `assert()` generates no code, and hence does nothing at all._ And further: _The error message includes the name of the file and function containing the `assert()` call, the source code line number of the call, and the text  of  the  argument_.

Comment: Not shown here, but aside [the parameter N in bio_write_gr](https://github.com/xbarin02/x-compressor/blob/76870ce81a059710aa30635ee4d5b15eacb9ce25/libx.c#L234) and [the local variable N in bio_read_gr](https://github.com/xbarin02/x-compressor/blob/76870ce81a059710aa30635ee4d5b15eacb9ce25/libx.c#L246) your current implementation also contains [a global variable named N](https://github.com/xbarin02/x-compressor/blob/76870ce81a059710aa30635ee4d5b15eacb9ce25/libx.c#L24). This makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Give the mode enum a name

While `enum`s are not strongly typed in C, it is more elegant to pretend they are. Give the `enum` you are declaring a type, and use it in `struct bio`, like so:

```
enum bio_mode {
    BIO_MODE_READ,
    BIO_MODE_WRITE,
};

struct bio {
    enum bio_mode mode;
    ...
};
```

Compilers can use this information, for example if you write a `switch (mode) {...}` statement and you forget to handle all possible modes, the compiler will warn about this.

Also change functions that take `int mode` as a parameter to `enum bio_mode mode`.

## Use standard types where possible

Use the standard fixed width integer types from [`<stdint.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) instead of inventing your own names. So instead of `uint32`, use `uint32_t`, and instead of `uchar`, use `uint8_t`.

There is no need to `assert()` that the size of `uint32_t` is 32 bits.

## Reorder `struct bio` to be more compact

On most 64-bit architectures, the layout of `struct bio` is suboptimal, because pointers and `size_t` have a 64-bit alignment, while `int`s have 32-bit alignment. I suggest the following:

```
struct bio {
    enum bio_mode mode;
    uint32_t b;
    uint8_t *ptr;
    size_t c;  
};
```

## Make `ptr` `uint32_t *`

Since you are casting `ptr` to `uint32_t *` in many places, it makes more sense to store it directly as that type, and only cast it once in `bio_open()`. I also recommend you take a `void *` in `bio_open()`, so there is no need for the caller to do any casting.

```
struct bio {
    enum bio_mode mode;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t *ptr;
    size_t c;  
};

static void bio_open(struct bio *bio, void *ptr, int mode)
{
    ...
    bio->ptr = ptr;
    ...
}
```

Remember to also change all occurrences of `bio->ptr += 4` to `bio->ptr++`.

## Assert that `ptr` is 32-bit aligned

Casting a pointer to an `uint32_t *` is only valid if the pointer is 32-bit aligned. On some architectures, accessing memory through a pointer that is not properly aligned is not allowed. On those that do, it might be less efficient than having the pointer properly aligned. To assert this write:

```
assert(((uintptr_t)ptr & 3) == 0);
```

Another option would be to allow `ptr` to be non-aligned in the call to `bio_open()`, but then to initialize `bio->b` such that it contains the first few bytes up to the first 32-bit aligned address, and of course set `bio->c` accordingly.

## Assert the right mode is set in `bio_read_*()` and `bio_write_*()`

To avoid accidental reuse of a `struct bio`, or mixing read and write calls on the same `bio`, `assert(bio->mode == BIO_MODE_READ)` in read functions, and so on.

## Optimizing `bio_write_bits()`

There's a lot of things in `bio_write_bits()` that can be optimized. First, there is a lot of unnecessary casting going. While it doesn't change the actual binary, it cleans up the source code to remove them, and makes it easier to see the actual equations. For example, you can just write:

```
bio->b |= (b & ((1 << m) - 1)) << bio->c;
```

In the above, you are masking the lower bits of `b` before shifting it by `bio->c`. However, this is completely unnecessary, as either those high bits were zero to begin with, or they will be shifted out anyway. So you can write:

```
bio->b |= b << bio->c;
```

More importantly, you have written this function as a loop, but you would only ever have at most two iterations of the loop: either all `n` bits fit in `bio->b`, or you have to flush once and put the rest of the bits in. You can rewrite the code as follows:

```
static void bio_write_bits(struct bio *bio, uint32_t b, size_t n)
{
    assert(n <= 32);
    assert((b >> n) == 0);
    assert(bio->c < 32);


    bio->b |= b << bio->c;
    bio->c += n;

    /* Exit early if we didn't fill bio->b yet */
    if (bio->c < 32)
        return;

    bio_flush_buffer(bio);

    /* Store the remaining bits */
    bio->c -= 32;
    bio->b = b >> (n - bio->c);
}
```

A similar optimization is possible for `bio_write_zero_bits()`.

## Reset `ptr` in `bio_close()`

To catch potential use of a `struct bio` after calling `bio_close()`, set `bio->ptr = NULL` in `bio_close()`.

## Validate your input

In `bio_read_unary()`, you have a loop reading zero bits. What if the input is malformed and just contains zero bits? After consuming the whole input, `bio_read_unary()` would continue reading past the end of the input.

First, you can get rid of the loop by just assuming you have to do at most two iterations, just like in `bio_write_bits()`. Second, it would be good to have an extra field in `struct bio` that is either the remaining size in the buffer, or the end pointer, and keep track of how much you have read and written. Don't use `assert()` to check that you don't go past the end, but use an actual `if`-statement, and return an error or at least call `abort()` if the input is invalid.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I have switched from C89 to C99, so now don't need to define my own type a can use the `uint32_t`. (This also greatly shortened the entire code.) Unfortunately, reordering the `struct bio` didn't improve the performance. Similarly, the masking the lower bits of `b` before shifting it by `bio->c` seems to be necessary, otherwise the more significant bits of `b` screw up the most significant bits of `bio->b` (which are  intended to be filled by future calls of the function). Anyhow, excellent answer!

Comment: The masking should not be necessary if the input to `bio_write_bits()` satisfies `(b >> n) == 0`. Either all bits fit in the first step, or they don't in which the ones that did not fit are shifted out. In the second step, `b` is shifted right so only those bits that didn't fit in the first step are left. Note that in the second step the result is directly assigned to `bio->b`, we don't OR it.