# Minimalist context compressor

Tags: performance, c, compression

I am working on an implementation of [the minimalist compression method](https://github.com/xbarin02/x-compressor).
The method is based on context modeling, followed by a simple entropy coder ([Golomb-Rice coder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236965/minimalist-golomb-rice-coder)).
The context model uses a single previous byte in the uncompressed symbol stream to predict the next byte.
At the moment, my implementation works quite well. 
However, I wonder if it is possible to make it faster or more concise.
Basically, any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

### Prerequisites

The implementation uses the following data structure:

```
struct context {
    size_t freq[256];          /* char -> frequency */
    unsigned char sorted[256]; /* index -> char */
    unsigned char order[256];  /* char -> index */
} table[256];
```

The functions `bio_open`, `bio_write_gr`, `bio_read_gr`, and `bio_close` implement the entropy (Golomb-Rice) coding.

Moreover, the function `void update_model(unsigned char delta)` updates the entropy model according to the newly encoded byte `delta` (not the subject of this review).

### Code

I use several two auxiliary functions:

```
static void swap_symbols(struct context *context, unsigned char c, unsigned char d)
{
    assert(context != NULL);

    unsigned char ic = context->order[c];
    unsigned char id = context->order[d];

    assert(context->sorted[ic] == c);
    assert(context->sorted[id] == d);

    context->sorted[ic] = d;
    context->sorted[id] = c;

    context->order[c] = id;
    context->order[d] = ic;
}

static void increment_frequency(struct context *context, unsigned char c)
{
    assert(context != NULL);

    unsigned char ic = context->order[c];
    size_t freq_c = ++(context->freq[c]);

    unsigned char *pd;

    for (pd = context->sorted + ic - 1; pd >= context->sorted; --pd) {
        if (freq_c <= context->freq[*pd]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    unsigned char d = *(pd + 1);

    if (c != d) {
        swap_symbols(context, c, d);
    }
}
```

The main entry functions are defined as follows:

```
void init()
{
    opt_k = 3;

    for (int p = 0; p < 256; ++p) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
            table[p].sorted[i] = i;
            table[p].freq[i] = 0;
            table[p].order[i] = i;
        }
    }
}

void *compress(void *iptr, size_t isize, void *optr)
{
    struct bio bio;
    unsigned char *end = (unsigned char *)iptr + isize;
    struct context *context = table + 0;

    bio_open(&bio, optr, BIO_MODE_WRITE);

    for (unsigned char *iptrc = iptr; iptrc < end; ++iptrc) {
        unsigned char c = *iptrc;

        /* get index */
        unsigned char d = context->order[c];

        bio_write_gr(&bio, opt_k, (uint32_t)d);

        assert(c == context->sorted[d]);

        /* update context model */
        increment_frequency(context, c);

        /* update Golomb-Rice model */
        update_model(d);

        context = table + c;
    }

    /* EOF symbol */
    bio_write_gr(&bio, opt_k, 256);

    bio_close(&bio, BIO_MODE_WRITE);

    return bio.ptr;
}

void *decompress(void *iptr, void *optr)
{
    struct bio bio;
    struct context *context = table + 0;

    bio_open(&bio, iptr, BIO_MODE_READ);

    unsigned char *optrc = optr;

    for (;; ++optrc) {
        uint32_t d = bio_read_gr(&bio, opt_k);

        if (d == 256) {
            break;
        }

        assert(d < 256);

        unsigned char c = context->sorted[d];

        *optrc = c;

        increment_frequency(context, c);

        update_model(d);

        context = table + c;
    }

    bio_close(&bio, BIO_MODE_READ);

    return optrc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Symbolic Constants

This code could use some symbolic constants:

```
struct context {
    size_t freq[256];          /* char -> frequency */
    unsigned char sorted[256]; /* index -> char */
    unsigned char order[256];  /* char -> index */
} table[256];

void init()
{
    opt_k = 3;

    for (int p = 0; p < 256; ++p) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
            table[p].sorted[i] = i;
            table[p].freq[i] = 0;
            table[p].order[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

The use of symbolic constants would make this code easier to write and maintain. For example if there was a symbolic constant for `256` the size of the table and the loop controls could be changed with a single line edit.

### Global Variables

In the function `init()` above, it is obvious that global variables are being used, `table` is on global variable and `opt_k` is another global variable.

Global variables are generally considered a bad programming practice, they make the code hard to write, debug and maintain. They also make it very easy to introduce bugs.

In the C programming language if the program consists of multiple files, it is possible that global variables can cause the program not to link if they are declared in multiple files.

### Using `assert()` in C

If at some point the code is going to be compiled for release using the optimizing feature of the compiler, then the `assert()` statements will be optimized away. If the error checking provided by the asserts is required it will be better to replace the asserts with if statements.

Comment: OP is explicitly using any `unsigned char` as an index. A good substitute for 256 would be `size_t freq[UCHAR_MAX +1u];`